# Facebook like box plugin not working on navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, html

I have added the facebook like box plugin code in my web application from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages

In my application there is only one html with body tag and I am dynamically adding 
other html with only div tag as per requirement to that html. I added the following code in one of such divs.

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/drsailablog" data-width="265px" 
    data-colorscheme="dark" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true">
</div>
```

I am following whatever mentioned in the directives to use the plugin i.e

```
        <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
(function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Now the problem is, its showing the respective like box for the home page while it gets loaded for the first time, but when I move through navigation bar from one menu option to other, I am only able to see the container where I wanted to show like box and no content there. I checked the calls, its not even sending any request to facebook. but if I refresh the page its sending request and I am able to see the content again. 
What am I doing wrong?? I have tried adding this function within script tag in that div also but still same issue is there i.e loading only on refresh